# Zend Framework: Action does not exist

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

This is my form generator function:

```
private function getAddArtistForm() {
  $form = new Zend_Form();
  $form->setAction("saveArtist");
  $form->setMethod("post");
  $form->setName("addartist");
  ...
}
public function newAction()
{
  $form = $this->getAddArtistForm();
  $this->view->form = $form;

}
```

I have also an action named `saveArtistAction`:

```
public function saveArtistAction() {
...
}
```

But when I submit the form I get the following error:

```
Message: Action "saveartist" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()
```

Request Parameters:

```
array (
  'controller' => 'artist',
  'action' => 'saveartist',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What if you specify `action` with hyphen:

```
'action' => 'save-artist',
```

?